# Pointer operation isn't changing its reference within a slice

Tags: go

I just started learning go. I have a question about pointers.

In the code below, the following line in the code doesn't do what I expect:

```
last_line.Next_line = &line // slice doesn't change
```

I want the slice to be changed as well, not only the local variable last_line.

What am I doing wrong?

```golang
type Line struct {
    Text           string
    Prev_line      *Line
    Next_line      *Line
}
var (
  lines     []Line
  last_line *Line
)

for i, record := range records {
  var prev_line *Line = nil
  text := record[0]
  if i > 0 {
    prev_line = &lines[i-1]
  }
  line := Line{
    Text:           text,
    Prev_line:      prev_line,
    Next_line:      nil}

  if last_line != nil {
    last_line.Next_line = &line // slice doesn't change
  }
  lines = append(lines, line)
  last_line = &line
}
```

Comment: Which slice are you talking about? `last_line`, `last_line.Next_line` and `line` are not slices. And please don't use underscore in your variable names. For slices in general, make sure you read [into to Slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro). You may also want to run `gofmt` on your code. And remember that `line` is a value, not a pointer. So `append` will append a copy of it to the `lines` slice.

Comment: Also, what is behind `records`? You can use [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/) to verify your code before posting here, too.

Comment: @Marc Why would you recommend not using underscores in your variable names? Snake case is veryy widely used. Is there any go specific reason, or is that just your preference?

Comment: It's just standard Go style to avoid snake_case and use camelCase instead. This fits fairly well with the use of uppercase for exported identifiers, e.g., ExportedThing vs hiddenThing.

Comment: Go is [mixed caps](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps) in most style guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Line` type is a fairly standard-looking doubly linked list.  Your `lines` variable holds a slice of these objects.  Combining these two is a bit unusual—not wrong, to be sure, just unusual.  And, as [Matt Oestreich notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64203144/go-pointer-operation-isnt-changing-its-reference-within-a-slice#comment113531316_64203144), we don't know quite what is in `records` (just that `range` can be used on it and that after doing so, we can use `record[0]` to get to a single `string` value), so there might be better ways to deal with things.

If `records` itself is a slice or has a sensible `len`, we can allocate a slice of `Line` instances all at once, of the appropriate size:

```
lines = make([]Line, len(records))
```

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/SRhu-sBJE4N) is a sample on the Go Playground that does it this way.

If we can't really get a suitable `len`—e.g., if `records` is a channel whose length is not really relevant—then we might indeed want to allocate individual lines, but in this case, it may be more sensible to *avoid* keeping them as a slice in the first place.  The doubly linked list alone will suffice.

Finally, if you really do want both a slice and this doubly linked list, note that using `append` may *copy* the slice's elements to a new, larger slice.  If and when it does so, the pointers in any elements you set up earlier will point into the old, *smaller* slice.  This is not invalid in terms of the language itself—those objects still exist and your pointers are keeping them "alive"—but it may not be what you intended at all.  In this case, it makes more sense to set all the pointers at the end, after building up the `lines` slice, just as in the sample code I provided.

(The sample I wrote is deliberately slightly weird in a way that is likely to get your homework or test grade knocked down a bit, if this was an attempt to cheat on homework or a test. :-) )

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I could just get rid of that slice and just use the linked list - I didn't think about that. What I wasn't aware was that "using append may copy the slice's elements to a new, larger slice" - this is what I think it's happening right now and why I'm losing reference to that pointer.